# Invalid value for key 'integrated security' in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm getting "*Invalid value for key 'integrated security'*". Please help me to resolve this.

```
SqlConnection cnTB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename="
  + databaseLocation + "Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30; User Instance=True");
```

Comment: Consider using SqlConnectionStringBuilder to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Assuming you've got your connections string from http://www.connectionstrings.com/ the issue would be some spelling error in the resulting value. Since you don't show exact connection string you'd need to spot the problem yourself (true/SSPI are possible misspellings).

Comment: i have given variable databaselocation as a connectionstring in my class

Answer (score 3):

You have forgot `;` before `Integrated`

Comment: no!  it does'nt work :( xtnd8

Comment: @SaadatHussain let me see how you do that, please.

Comment: simply i put ; before integrated

Comment: There should be a typo somewhere. @SaadatHussain

Comment: yes May be tht's why m asking for help :)

Comment: @SaadatHussain what's coming with `databaseLocation`, did you checked this out?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure since I don't know what's inside your `databaseLocation` variable, but I think you're missing semicolon before *Integrated Security* (like xtnd8 mentioned in his post). Also, since you're using verbatim string (*@*) there might be problem depending on what you have saved inside your `databaseLocation` variable. Try declaring your *connectionString* this way:

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = @".\SQLEXPRESS",
    AttachDBFilename = databaseLocation,
    IntegratedSecurity = true,
    ConnectTimeout = 30,
    UserInstance = true
};

SqlConnection cnTB = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```